# Chart in CListview

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am using `ChartJS` extension to show a bar graph. But i don't know how to implement it dynamically, so i use `Clistview` to update the chart values but it is not working, Is there any way to update the bar values using `listview` or without `listview`.

I have age range comming from database dynamically in search for when i click on search age range changes show without refreshing the page i want to change the grpah values.

**Here's the code i use in `listview` page:**

```
$this->widget(
            'chartjs.widgets.ChBars', 
            array(
                'id' => 'tbl-age-range',
                'width' => 600,
                'height' => 300,
                'htmlOptions' => array(),
                'labels' => array("18-24","25-34","35-44"),
                'datasets' => array(
                    array(
                        "fillColor" => "#ff00ff",
                        "strokeColor" => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        "data" => array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
                    )       
                ),
                'options' => array()
            )
        );
```

I want to change value like ajax not on load.

Comment: can you explain a bit more, what data you want to display?

Comment: i edited my question.